# Write pipe blocking when pipe-max-size is set

Tags: c++, pipe, ioctl

I am writing in a pipe with c++. The `write` method is blocking even that there is available space in the pipe. The problem happens when I set pipe size to the value in `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size`.

I created the pipe then set max pipe size with `F_SETPIPE_SZ`:

```
int maxPipeSize = 1048576; // cat /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size
if (fcntl(my_pipe, F_SETPIPE_SZ, maxPipeSize) != maxPipeSize) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting pipe size\n");
    return;
}
```

To write I check the current size in pipe with `FIONREAD`:

```
size_t currentPipeSize = 0;
if (ioctl(my_pipe, FIONREAD, &currentPipeSize)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't get pipe size\n");
    return;
}
```

After that, I check if current pipe size plus size to write is greater than `maxPipeSize`:

```
int size = 1000; // size to write
char data[size]; // sample data

if (currentPipeSize + size > maxPipeSize) {
    fprintf(stderr, "There is no space in pipe\n");
    return;
}
```

Then when the pipe size is 1024000 the write method blocks:

```
size_t capacity = fcntl(my_pipe, F_GETPIPE_SZ); // debug
fprintf(stderr, "size: %lu, available: %lu\n", currentPipeSize, capacity - currentPipeSize); // debug

ssize_t writtenBytes = write(my_pipe, data, size);
```

The output until block is:

```
...
size: 1015000, available: 33576
size: 1016000, available: 32576
size: 1017000, available: 31576
size: 1018000, available: 30576
size: 1019000, available: 29576
size: 1020000, available: 28576
size: 1021000, available: 27576
size: 1022000, available: 26576
size: 1023000, available: 25576
size: 1024000, available: 24576
```

Comment: Can you find a more granular break-off point by writing say 1-byte buffers at a time? That number should be googleable together with `pipe-max-size` and "blocking" and your distro name/kernel version.

Comment: You wanted 1 MiB and got it, but it stops at 1024 kB. Odd... Is it a filesystem pipe, a `pipe()` or a unix domain socket? I don't know if it makes any difference but may be good to know for someone who knows better. What does `ulimit -a` say? Do you have a max quota on your account?

Comment: Btw, did you try `F_GETPIPE_SZ` directly after your `F_SETPIPE_SZ`?

Comment: @sehe Thanks for the suggestion, when I write 1 byte at time the pipe fill completelly, below the logs:

...
size: 1048569, available: 7
size: 1048570, available: 6
size: 1048571, available: 5
size: 1048572, available: 4
size: 1048573, available: 3
size: 1048574, available: 2
size: 1048575, available: 1

Comment: @TedLyngmo I created the pipe with `pipe (int __pipedes[2])` from unistd method. The `ulimit -a` produces (I removed unusefull lines):
```
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo After set `F_SETPIPE_SZ`, the value get with `F_GETPIPE_SZ` is the expected: 1048576

Comment: Ok, since you can fill it to 1 GiB one byte at a time, there's no OS limit that prevents it. What if you set the buffer to exactly 1024 kB? Are you still able to fill it to 1024000 if you use 1000 char buffers?

Comment: When I use 1,2,3 or 4 bytes at time the pipe is filled, but when I use 5 nope:

...
size: 1048300, available: 276 - 
size: 1048305, available: 271 - 
size: 1048310, available: 266 - 
size: 1048315, available: 261 - 
size: 1048320, available: 256


When I use 1024 as you siggested the pipe is filled correctly. The problem is in how many bytes I use at time.

Comment: With these in hand, I say it's time to look in libc/kernel. Do you have the option to use oterh libc (libmusl?) or compare other kernel platforms? [This is "going deep" so don't forget to keep looking "wide"]